# See time in a different timezone than UTC

Tags: discussion, feature-request, timezone

Stack Overflow shows time in UTC. Instead, I want to see time in UTC + 5:30 (Indian Standard Time). Is there any facility on Stack Overflow to see time depending on region/country?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80532/172661

Comment: There is an extension called stackoverflow extras that you can get which will do many things one of which is show times in your local time and requires tampermonkey to run.

Comment: @JoeW Where can i find that extension?

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox and it has instructions on installing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. Of course, if you use the site enough, you tend to memorize what time UTC Midnight is in your timezone.

Comment: And twice a year (more often if you travel), you get to recalibrate.